# Affecting a page from a class in wp7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, events, binding

I'm calling a web service in a class and needs the result in some page in my project. How could I execute something in my page when the event in that class is fired? note: the calling is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your view model. Simply bind the view model to your page and when anything changes in the background (e.g. asynchronously), the view should be updated.

Try to use MVVM in your applications and you will be good to go. Also, note you can place view model globally in the App class. This will make it easy to update from one place since everyone has access to App.